# MySQL 5.7 vs 5.5 and .ibd files

Tags: mysql, innodb

We recently did a migration from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.7, on two different servers. For the migration, we used a master-slave replication. The old DB (5.5) was set as master, the new one as slave (5.7).

Everything went well and the migration was successful. The DB is large, about 600G of data.

The problem we have now is that on the new DB, ther is one large .ibd file of 82G. Let's asume the DB name is my_database. This file is located under:
`/var/lib/mysql/my_database`:

```
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  82G Apr 20 10:28 articles.ibd
```

The articles table is big, but why there is such large ibd file on the new MySQL server, and was not there on the old one.

As we have now some storage limits (SSD), we would like to somehow delete this file. How to do it and why this file is created there on MySQL5.7?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html

Comment: Thank you @MrTux, I already saw this option and set it to OFF, but are we allowed to then remove the existing ibd files without crashing mysql or lose data?

Comment: ALL THE ARTICLE DATA IS IN `articles.ibd`; DO NOT REMOVE IT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just run `ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] ENGINE=InnoDB ALGORITHM=COPY;` after disabling [`innodb_file_per_table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table).

cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tablespace-copying.html and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136250/migrate-from-innodb-file-per-table-to-off-in-mysql-alter-table-removing-ibd-file, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html

Comment: Works as a charm. you made my day @MrTux.